# How to show 0 in column if no match is found?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm doing a left join on two tables.  Table one shows potential users while the other table shows actual users.  Potential user is someone in a location who could potentially use our application.  Actual user is someone in a location who has in fact used our application.

So I want three columns reported.  Location, Actual Users, Potential Users

Now, I want to always show the potential user number -- even when actual users is 0, too.  This is no problem.  Potential users will show 0 in the field (its 0 in the source table).

But if actual user is 0, its displaying blank.  How can I display this as 0 in Access?

```
Potential Users Table 

Location   | Potential    
-----------+---------  
New Jersey | 4  
Ohio       | 2

Actual Users Table  

Location   | Actual  
-----------+---------  
Ohio       | 1
```

Right now, if I do a left join.  It'll show:

```
Location   | Potential | Actual 
-----------+-----------+------- 
New Jersey | 4         |   
Ohio       | 2         | 1
```

What I'd like to do is for New Jersey to show a 0 in the Actual column.  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to me you have a schema error -- users and potential users should all be in the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Nz(Actual, 0) AS Actual
```

Other option removed

Comment: When Actual is Null, that IIf expression will return Null (**not** 0), the same as this expression: `IIf(Null <> Null, 0, Null)`

Comment: @HansUp I understand ANSI NULL behavior.  Access doesn't seem to handle the IS NULL or IS NOT NULL in the IIf either, so I'll just remove that option.

Comment: I thought IIf was a worthwhile addition in case the OP (or anyone else reading your answer) runs a query in a context where the expression service, and hence the Nz() function, is unavailable.  This expression will return 0 whenever Actual is Null, otherwise the value of Actual: `IIf(Actual Is Null, 0, Actual)`

Comment: @HansUp - I couldn't get that to work in Access 2010 - I tend to avoid Access anyway.  Also going through Jet can often change queries not in Access itself.

Comment: @Cade Roux--For Access, use the Access function: `Iif(IsNull(Actual),0,Actual)`

Comment: That surprised me, Cade.  I haven't installed 2010.  But I tested queries which included `IIf(Actual Is Null, 0, Actual)` under both 2003 and 2007 ... they worked as intended.  Just to be clear, trying the same IIf expression in the Immediate Window throws error #424 (Object required), but the database engines accept it in a query without complaint.  I would use Roland's IsNull() suggestion in the IIf expression if `Actual Is Null` is rejected.

Comment: @HansUp This was in the query designer in SQL mode.  I tend to stick with SQL Server and Oracle, and 2010 has rearranged a lot of things too.

Comment: The reason it throws an error in the immediate window is because "Is Null" is SQL, not VBA.

Comment: @Cade: going through Jet makes no changes to your SQL string, though certainly if you paste it into the query designer inside Access, Access makes changes. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're asserting there.

Answer (score -4):

Try using as follows

```
 COALESCE(Actual, 0)
```

Comment: He needs Access syntax, not SQL.

Comment: actually my first thought was COALESCE and then I looked at the tag... eheh